# Why can Unit be assigned to a Tuple without compilation error?

Tags: scala

Check this REPL session, under Scala 2.12.10:

```
scala> val a = 3 match { case 3 => 1 case 4 => println("why") }
a: AnyVal = 1

scala> val a: Int = 3 match { case 3 => 1 case 4 => println("why") }
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Int
       val a: Int = 3 match { case 3 => 1 case 4 => println("why") }

scala> val (a, b) = 3 match { case 3 => (1, 2) case 4 => println("why") }
a: Any = 1
b: Any = 2

scala> val (a: Int, b) = 3 match { case 3 => (1, 2) case 4 => println("why") }
a: Int = 1
b: Any = 2

scala> val (a, b) = 4 match { case 3 => (1, 2) case 4 => println("why") }
why
scala.MatchError: () (of class scala.runtime.BoxedUnit)
  ... 36 elided
```

I would expect the snippets with tuples to not compile as if Unit is ever returned from the second match, then you always get a runtime error. Why does Unit match successfully to Tuple2 in the compiler view?

Comment: Why? `Unit` is a type, valid unless there is a contradictory type ascription

Comment: Is Unit supposed to be matchable with (a, b)? How would that even work?

Comment: The Least Upper Bound of `Tuple2` and `Unit` is `Any`. A value of `Any` _could_ be a tuple so that match compiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Unit` **cannot** be assigned to a `Tuple`

```
val t: (Int, Int) = ()  // Error: type mismatch; found: Unit required: (Int, Int)
```

However the following syntax represents proper **pattern matching**

```
val (a: Int, b: Int) = ...
```

which in your case desugars to something like so

```
val x: Any = 3 match {
  case 3 => (1, 2)
  case 4 => println("why")
}

val a: Int = x match {
  case t: (_, _) if t._1.isInstanceOf[Int] => t._1.asInstanceOf[Int]
}

val b: Int = x match {
  case t: (_, _) if t._2.isInstanceOf[Int] => t._2.asInstanceOf[Int]
}
```

Notice those `asInstanceOf[Int]` which convince compiler static type of `a` and `b` is `Int`, however what would happen at runtime is a different story. For example, consider

```
val t: (Int, Int) = println("why").asInstanceOf[(Int, Int)]
```

which compiles but fails a runtime.

---

Analysing `-Xprint:jvm` output of

```
lazy val (a: Int, b: Int) = (): Any
```

we have approximately

```
val t: Tuple2 = {
  val x1: Any = ()
  if (x1.isInstanceOf[Tuple2]) {
    val x2: Tuple2 = x1.asInstanceOf[Tuple2]
    val a: Any = x2._1
    val b: Any = x2._2
    if (a.isInstanceOf[Int]) {
      val x3: Int = scala.Int.unbox(a)   // in effect asInstanceOf[Int]
      if (b.isInstanceOf[Int]) {
        val x4: Int = scala.Int.unbox(b) // in effect asInstanceOf[Int]
        new Tuple2(x3, x4)
      } else throw new MatchError(x1)
    } else throw new MatchError(x1)
  } else throw new MatchError(x1)
}

def a: Int = t._1
def b: Int = t._2
```

whilst

```
lazy val (a: Int, b: Int) = ()
```

does not compile, hence if expression on the right of `=`, in pattern value definition, types to `Any` it makes all the difference.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the difference between this case and the case that did produce a compilation error?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Are you referring to `val a: Int = 3 match...`?

Comment: Yes, that's the one.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Note the difference between **pattern value definition** `val (a: Int, b: Int) = expr`, and regular value definition `val a: Int = expr`. The former result in pattern matching whilst the latter does not. What might be confusing the matter is that `expr` in question just happens to be a pattern matching expression itself, however this is not actually important, because this `expr` will itself be pattern matched further (in the case of `val (a, b)`) and it is this second pattern match that convinces the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Since your partial function can return either a `Tuple2[Int, Int]` or a `Unit`, the compiler considers its return type to be the "smallest common supertype" of those two types, that is `Any` :

```
scala> val x = 4 match { case 3 => (1, 2) case 4 => println("why") }
why
x: Any = ()
```

Notice how the return value is `x: Any = ()` and not `x: Unit = ()`.

What you're doing when extracting the tuple is equivalent to this, which compiles (since Any is a supertype of Tuple2), but produces a MatchError:

```
scala> val (a, b) = ().asInstanceOf[Any]
scala.MatchError: () (of class scala.runtime.BoxedUnit)
  ... 28 elided
```

Comment: Why doesn't that happen with the one that can return either `Int` or `Unit`, then?